# How to prevent HTML code in a literal inside a DIV from affecting outer page styles

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a page(that uses a master page), that has a literal control inside a DIV in which I load a HTML source from a database record that I don't have control over(the HTML comes from MS Word documents).
My page looks good until I load the document into the literal. Then some elements belonging to the master page have their styles affected. Seems to me that there are CSS styles in the document I'm loading that are affecting the master page elements.

Any idea of how I can isolate the outer page from the HTML I'm loading?

Here is part of the containing (outer) page:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">  
        <div id="sowDiv" style="overflow:scroll; width:800; height:500px">
            <!-- The literal control loads the MS Word HTML source -->
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="sowLiteral" ></asp:Literal>                                                                            
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using an IFrame in conjunction with an Http Handler.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">  
        <iframe src="GetContent.ashx?id=<%=Id%>" style="border:0px;" height="500px" width="800px">Loading...</iframe>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In web.config, under HttpHandlers, you'd need to add a http handler for this:

```
<add verb="GET" path="GetContent.ashx" type="MyApp.ContentHandler"/>
```

The http handler would return the html for your word document (from the database):

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class ContentHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            // This needs some better error handling
            int id = (int) context.Request.QueryString.Get("id");

            // Get content from database
            string content = GetContentById(id);

            // Display the content
            context.Response.Write(content);
            context.Response.End();
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would be advisable to add some additional security around the http handler to ensure that the ID can't just be changed to return any content to unauthorized users, but this should serve as a good starting point.

(On a side note, if you do need to get any data from the session for authentication, don't forget to add IReadOnlySessionState to the http handler so that it can access the session).

Answer (score 2):

*Don't allow unexpected data in the literal control* -- take the input and turn it into an acceptable (excpected) output during a transformation layer.

However, since this is a good bit of work (unless there is a library for this? :-) then, as a quick"fix", consider an iframe.

At the very least an iframe can *generally* reveal if the literal control is indeed the culprit although so could a full HTML/CSS inspection.

Happy coding.

Comment: Yes, IFRAME is what you want for this. Also remember there are HTML Script Injection implications here, so you will need to sanitize the HTML whether you use an IFRAME or DIV.

Answer (score 1):

I use in .aspx:

```
<div id="dvEjemplo" runat="server" style="border-style: inset; border-width: thin">
  <asp:Literal ID="litEjemplo" runat="server" Mode="encode" visible="false">     </asp:Literal>
  <asp:Label ID="lblEjemplo" runat="server" Height="380px"></asp:Label>
```

and the code (aspx.cs)

```
public string Fundamento
{
    set
    {
        this.litEjemplo.Text = value;
        this.lblEjemplo.Text = this.litEjemplo.Text;
    }
}
```